# Does my ISP intentionally hiding ip ? or MITM being done? because always third hop in my route is being not responding

Tags: traceroute, hping

i have run all these commands below to try to figure out third hop in my trace route , not being lucky to find ip , please advice , also for your consideration my ISP is Du in Dubai, UAE , how to find ip for third hop , is there a way ?
`mtr -U google.com`

````
acir.local (192.168.1.116) -> google.com (142.250.181.46)                                                      2023-06-05T11:23:01+0400
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
     ckets               Pings
 Host                                                                                         Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 192.168.1.1                                                                               58.3%    85  7013. 1920.   3.7 7013. 1756.
 2. 192.168.70.1                                                                              58.3%    85  11016 3722.   8.4 11016 2709.
 3. (waiting for reply)
 4. 10.142.57.141                                                                             61.9%    85  18026 8417. 1005. 18026 3744.
    10.100.136.34
    10.100.137.77
 5. 10.100.137.86                                                                             61.9%    85  21027 8699. 2006. 21027 4079.
 6. (waiting for reply)
 7. 10.100.144.9                                                                              63.1%    85  25031 14662 5008. 25031 4846.
    10.17.40.109
    10.254.41.249
    10.254.41.253
 8. (waiting for reply)
 9. 172.253.51.55                                                                             67.9%    85  17027 11569 4007. 18016 3643.
    172.253.51.205
10. 142.251.50.213                                                                            67.9%    85  20028 12237 3006. 20028 3738.
    142.251.50.211
11. fjr04s06-in-f14.1e100.net                                                                 58.3%    85  40049 19937 10011 40049 7010.```
````

`traceroute google.com`  this's usually happens in traceroute

```
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  5.263 ms  1.096 ms  3.895 ms
 2  192.168.70.1 (192.168.70.1)  2.022 ms  1.532 ms  1.455 ms
 3  * * *
 4  10.142.57.141 (10.142.57.141)  4.724 ms
    10.100.136.34 (10.100.136.34)  8.350 ms
    10.100.137.77 (10.100.137.77)  4.721 ms
 5  10.100.137.86 (10.100.137.86)  5.127 ms  4.964 ms  4.957 ms
 6  10.17.40.109 (10.17.40.109)  15.318 ms
    10.254.41.253 (10.254.41.253)  11.774 ms  8.695 ms
 7  10.17.40.109 (10.17.40.109)  12.398 ms
    10.254.41.253 (10.254.41.253)  9.982 ms
    10.254.41.249 (10.254.41.249)  11.794 ms
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  74.125.253.226 (74.125.253.226)  11.832 ms
    216.239.59.2 (216.239.59.2)  8.613 ms
    142.251.51.58 (142.251.51.58)  11.218 ms
11  142.251.50.213 (142.251.50.213)  10.323 ms  8.705 ms  8.545 ms
12  fjr04s06-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.181.46)  7.684 ms  8.139 ms  6.810 ms
```

`sudo hping -S -T -p 443 --fast facebook.com` however in hping always resolve in 433 and 80

```
HPING facebook.com (en0 157.240.7.35): S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
hop=1 TTL 0 during transit from ip=192.168.1.1 name=UNKNOWN
hop=1 hoprtt=4.1 ms
hop=2 TTL 0 during transit from ip=192.168.70.1 name=UNKNOWN
hop=2 hoprtt=2.0 ms

4: hop=4 TTL 0 during transit from ip=10.100.137.77 name=UNKNOWN
hop=4 hoprtt=4.7 ms
hop=5 TTL 0 during transit from ip=10.100.137.86 name=UNKNOWN
hop=5 hoprtt=4.7 ms
hop=6 TTL 0 during transit from ip=10.229.200.106 name=UNKNOWN
hop=6 hoprtt=87.8 ms
hop=7 TTL 0 during transit from ip=157.240.84.166 name=ae3.pr04.sin1.tfbnw.net
hop=7 hoprtt=83.8 ms
hop=8 TTL 0 during transit from ip=129.134.55.112 name=po204.asw04.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=8 hoprtt=82.4 ms
hop=9 TTL 0 during transit from ip=147.75.223.149 name=po218.psw04.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=9 hoprtt=83.8 ms
hop=10 TTL 0 during transit from ip=147.75.223.143 name=po215.psw04.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=10 hoprtt=117.1 ms
hop=11 TTL 0 during transit from ip=147.75.222.85 name=po244.psw01.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=11 hoprtt=382.9 ms
hop=12 TTL 0 during transit from ip=157.240.38.137 name=UNKNOWN
hop=12 hoprtt=558.8 ms
hop=13 TTL 0 during transit from ip=157.240.38.197 name=UNKNOWN
hop=13 hoprtt=479.3 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=32 win=65535 rtt=204.2 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=33 win=65535 rtt=102.2 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=34 win=65535 rtt=85.1 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=35 win=65535 rtt=82.3 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=36 win=65535 rtt=81.7 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=37 win=65535 rtt=83.3 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=38 win=65535 rtt=83.0 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=39 win=65535 rtt=85.9 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=40 win=65535 rtt=83.1 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=41 win=65535 rtt=90.1 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=42 win=65535 rtt=84.8 ms
DUP! len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=32 win=65535 rtt=1138.2 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=43 win=65535 rtt=81.9 ms
DUP! len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=33 win=65535 rtt=1120.3 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=44 win=65535 rtt=81.7 ms
DUP! len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=34 win=65535 rtt=1146.1 ms
DUP! len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=35 win=65535 rtt=1098.6 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=45 win=65535 rtt=83.7 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=46 win=65535 rtt=82.2 ms
DUP! len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=36 win=65535 rtt=1113.7 ms
len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=47 win=65535 rtt=84.9 ms
DUP! len=44 ip=157.240.7.35 ttl=85 DF id=0 sport=443 flags=SA seq=37 win=65535 rtt=1111.3 ms
^C
--- facebook.com hping statistic ---
49 packets tramitted, 35 packets received, 29% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 2.0/297.1/1146.1 ms
```

`sudo MTR -U google.com`

```
Host                                                                                        Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 192.168.1.1                                                                               0.0%    26    1.0   1.6   1.0   6.2   1.2
 2. 192.168.70.1                                                                              0.0%    26    1.6   2.0   1.6   4.9   0.7
 3. (waiting for reply)
 4. 10.100.137.77                                                                             0.0%    26    4.4   5.2   4.3   8.1   1.1
 5. 10.100.137.86                                                                             0.0%    26    4.9   5.2   4.3   7.7   0.9
 6. 10.17.40.109                                                                              0.0%    25   10.5  11.1   8.0  13.5   1.5
 7. 10.17.40.109                                                                              0.0%    25   11.3   9.4   7.3  12.7   1.5
 8. (waiting for reply)
 9. 172.253.51.205                                                                            0.0%    25    9.2   9.3   8.2  12.4   1.2
10. 142.251.50.213                                                                            0.0%    25    8.3   9.2   7.8  18.0   2.6
11. fjr04s06-in-f14.1e100.net                                                                 0.0%    25    6.4   6.8   6.0   8.9   0.7
```

`sudo MTR -T google.com` 
here too usually MTR -T resolve this issue and cover hop ips that in ICMP are not responding

```
 Host                                                                                         Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 192.168.1.1                                                                               90.0%    51  8007. 3408.   7.7 8007. 3435.
 2. 192.168.70.1                                                                              86.0%    51  7011. 3439.   2.9 8023. 2997.
 3. (waiting for reply)
 4. 10.142.57.141                                                                             84.0%    51  9013. 7765. 1002. 13027 4374.
    10.100.137.77
    10.100.136.34
 5. 10.100.137.86                                                                             88.0%    51  10014 6347. 2003. 10023 3146.
 6. (waiting for reply)
 7. 10.17.40.109                                                                              84.0%    51  12015 9391. 3004. 14026 3549.
    10.100.144.9
    10.254.41.249
    10.254.41.253
 8. (waiting for reply)
 9. 172.253.51.55                                                                             88.0%    51  11013 9182. 4003. 13025 3195.
    172.253.51.205
10. 142.251.50.211                                                                            88.0%    51  13016 9349. 5003. 13016 3272.
    142.251.50.213
11. fjr04s06-in-f14.1e100.net                                                                 79.6%    50  14037 16131 1007. 28
```

`sudo hping -S -T -p 443 --fast facebook.com`

here i got very weird result which being looped back which could be an MITM .
he output in hop 3 being looped back could be a sign of a man-in-the-middle attack. A man-in-the-middle attack is a type of cyberattack where an attacker secretly relays and alters data between two parties who believe they are directly communicating with each other. In this case, the attacker would be able to see all of the traffic between your computer and Facebook, and they could potentially modify that traffic.

There are a few reasons why hop 3 being looped back could be a sign of a man-in-the-middle attack. First, it is unusual for traffic to be looped back to the same device. Second, the attacker could be using hop 3 to monitor your traffic and potentially modify it. Third, the attacker could be using hop 3 to inject malicious code into your computer.

```
HPING facebook.com (en0 157.240.7.35): S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
hop=1 TTL 0 during transit from ip=192.168.1.1 name=UNKNOWN
hop=1 hoprtt=4.5 ms
hop=2 TTL 0 during transit from ip=192.168.70.1 name=UNKNOWN
hop=2 hoprtt=1.6 ms
hop=3 TTL 0 during transit from ip=192.168.1.1 name=UNKNOWN
hop=3 hoprtt=0.0 ms
hop=4 TTL 0 during transit from ip=192.168.70.1 name=UNKNOWN
hop=4 hoprtt=0.0 ms
hop=5 TTL 0 during transit from ip=10.100.137.86 name=UNKNOWN
hop=5 hoprtt=4.9 ms
hop=6 TTL 0 during transit from ip=10.44.24.222 name=UNKNOWN
hop=6 hoprtt=88.9 ms
hop=7 TTL 0 during transit from ip=157.240.84.166 name=ae3.pr04.sin1.tfbnw.net
hop=7 hoprtt=86.3 ms
hop=8 TTL 0 during transit from ip=129.134.55.112 name=po204.asw04.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=8 hoprtt=82.8 ms
hop=9 TTL 0 during transit from ip=129.134.32.68 name=po204.asw01.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=9 hoprtt=371.4 ms
hop=10 TTL 0 during transit from ip=129.134.55.112 name=po204.asw04.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=10 hoprtt=751.9 ms
hop=11 TTL 0 during transit from ip=129.134.32.68 name=po204.asw01.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=11 hoprtt=648.9 ms
hop=12 TTL 0 during transit from ip=129.134.64.3 name=po249.psw03.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=12 hoprtt=420.4 ms
hop=13 TTL 0 during transit from ip=147.75.222.121 name=po232.psw02.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=13 hoprtt=821.3 ms
hop=14 TTL 0 during transit from ip=147.75.222.87 name=po245.psw01.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=14 hoprtt=1509.3 ms
hop=15 TTL 0 during transit from ip=147.75.223.43 name=po213.psw02.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=15 hoprtt=1790.2 ms
hop=16 TTL 0 during transit from ip=147.75.223.133 name=po204.psw04.sin6.tfbnw.net
hop=16 hoprtt=2539.3 ms
```

`traceroute facebook.com`

```
traceroute to facebook.com (157.240.7.35), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  2.805 ms  0.979 ms  0.934 ms
 2  192.168.70.1 (192.168.70.1)  2.248 ms  1.468 ms  1.346 ms
 3  * * *
 4  10.100.137.77 (10.100.137.77)  6.416 ms  5.391 ms
    10.100.136.34 (10.100.136.34)  7.631 ms
 5  10.100.137.86 (10.100.137.86)  12.224 ms  5.062 ms  5.500 ms
 6  10.229.200.106 (10.229.200.106)  84.257 ms  84.369 ms
    10.44.24.222 (10.44.24.222)  90.128 ms
 7  ae3.pr04.sin1.tfbnw.net (157.240.84.166)  83.489 ms  83.532 ms  96.837 ms
 8  po204.asw02.sin6.tfbnw.net (129.134.34.240)  85.552 ms
    po204.asw03.sin6.tfbnw.net (129.134.55.108)  83.548 ms
    po204.asw01.sin6.tfbnw.net (129.134.32.68)  84.732 ms
 9  po244.psw02.sin6.tfbnw.net (147.75.222.133)  82.941 ms
    po290.psw02.sin6.tfbnw.net (129.134.64.1)  82.726 ms
    po273.psw03.sin6.tfbnw.net (129.134.64.27)  85.824 ms
10  157.240.38.253 (157.240.38.253)  83.075 ms
    157.240.38.225 (157.240.38.225)  83.698 ms
    173.252.67.3 (173.252.67.3)  86.283 ms
11  edge-star-mini-shv-01-sin6.facebook.com (157.240.7.35)  83.576 ms  83.417 ms  83.534 ms
```